# java simple login system implementation file not loading

Tags: java, file, directory, bufferedreader, filereader

I have an assignment to make a simple "login" system for a messaging application that lets users login, make an account and delete an account. When a new account is made a new folder is made with that username to store that users messages. When the program is run I am making it scan through this directory on startup to look at what users there are already and add them to the programs arraylist of users, however the user is not loaded for some reason. Please can someone tell me where I am going wrong? Here is the portion of my code responsible for loading on startup. In each "INFO.txt" file for each user, there is a one line string which states the username and password seperated by ":".

The MAIN ISSUE I am having here is that when I call a method which looks through my arraylist of users, the only user that already exists (george) has not been added to my arraylist of users.

I have also included a screenshot of how the folder structure is in eclipse so you can see if I have entered the path information wrong. Thanks

[image]

```
public class MessagingApp {

private Scanner scanner;
private ArrayList<User> userList; //All users currently registered
private User currentUser; //The user currently logged in

public MessagingApp() {

    scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    userList = new ArrayList<User>();

    try {
        this.load();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //this.start();

}

/**
 * loads all user information currently stored 
 * @throws IOException 
 */
private void load() throws IOException {

    Path users = Paths.get("users");
    File usersDir = users.toFile();
    String[] entries = usersDir.list(); //Each string in this list represents a user folder

    if(entries!=null) {

        for(String s: entries) {

            Path thisUser = Paths.get("users/"+s);
            File thisUserDir = thisUser.toFile();
            String[] userFiles = thisUserDir.list();

            for(String file: userFiles) {

                if( file.equals("INFO.txt") ) {

                    try {

                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("users/"+s+"/INFO.txt"));
                        String info = reader.readLine();
                        String[] credentials = info.split(":");
                        userList.add(new User(credentials[0],credentials[1]));

                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }

                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the [edit] link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: The point is: give us the means to *repro* the issue.

Comment: @GhostCat I have now updated my post, see the "MAIN ISSUE" section. Does this make my problem more clear?

Comment: An immediately obvious thing is that your code looks for a file named `INFO.txt` where the file in your folder screenshot is named `INFO.txt.txt`. Didn't look further than that so maybe there are other issues too.

Comment: You're looking for file `INFO.txt` while the directory contains `INFO.txt.txt`

Comment: This seems to have solved the issue. I didn't realise specifying a files file extension makes the file name have it twice. Thanks!